# Join in one column the common information

Tags: r

I have the next table

```
tb <- data.frame(Name=c(rep("John",4),rep("Peter",2),rep("Mary",3)),
             Char=c("CharA","CharB","Charc","CharD","CharB","CharE","CharA","CharC","CharD")
             )
```

Is it possible to create a table like this to summarize the information in the second column per Name?.

```
 tb.res <- data.frame(Name=c("John","Peter","Mary"),
                 Resume=c("CharA,CharB,CharC,CharD","CharB,CharE","CharA,CharC,CharD"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tb)[, list(Resume=toString(Char)), Name]
```

Or use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Char~Name, tb, paste, collapse=',')
```